# Add html to jquery text function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am editing the wordpress js and was unable to do so as I am not a jquery expert so i decided to post question here i am wondering to set the font size of AM or PM to small but in js the html is not working i know that would be possible as when i place html tags it is not converting just showing as html output

```
$time.text(hours + ":" + minutes +  ampm);
```

at the place of ampm i would like to wrap it up with

si i tried to do like this

```
$time.text(hours + ":" + minutes +"<p class='small'>" + ampm + "</p>");
```

the output is coming as

```
03:25 <p class='small'> PM </p>
```

so the html is harcoded not converting can anyone help me out with this concern ?

Comment: is time an id or class? Shouldn't it be inside brackets?

Comment: Use `.html` instead of `.text`

Comment: @JohnC You could have posted it as an answer itself ;-)

Comment: Not a direct dupe but it'll explain what the problem is and how it can be solved. There'll be other hundreds of direct dupes but this is better as it explains both `text` and `html`.

Comment: @Abhi yeah I know, it just felt a bit short for an answer

Comment: okay so .html will do the same as .text do but difference will be it wil convert show the html right ?

Comment: @UsmanKhan `html()` will render the HTML whereas `text()` will encode the HTML to entities and will show the text on page. See the link above question to know the difference between `html()` and `text()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

change `.text` to [`.html`](http://api.jquery.com/html/):-

```
$time.html(hours + ":" + minutes +"<p class='small'>" + ampm + "</p>");
```

**jQuery Docmentation**

`.text` = Set the content of each element in the set of matched elements to the specified text.

`.html` = Set the HTML contents of each element in the set of matched elements.

Answer (score 4):

`.html()` treats/interpret the string as HTML whereas `.text()` treats the content as text

Thus you need to use`.html()` instead of `.text()`:

```
$time.html(hours + ":" + minutes +"<p class='small'>" + ampm + "</p>");
```